# There is no implicit conversion from CustomObject to System.IConvertible

Tags: c#

Stuck on this for a while now and I dont understand what is going on. I have an Object of Level which populates on App start. Object has 3 classes. I need to return different Object depending on type `T` on my method but I keep getting this error. This is my first time having to deal with conversions of types on the same method.

`There is no implicit conversion from uCue_Silver.Models.Game to System.IConvertible`

Many Thanks in Advance.

Level Single File Object

```
public class Level
{
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public string game { get; set; }
    public List<Word> words { get; set; }
}

public class Word
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public string ipa { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string sound { get; set; }
    public string video { get; set; }
}
```

Method

```
public T GetResources<T>(int level = 1, int word = 1, string gameVersion = "bronze", bool shouldReturnGamesOnly = false) where T : IConvertible
{
    if (versions.Contains(gameVersion))
    {
        if (!shouldReturnGamesOnly)
        {
            if (gameVersion.ToLower() == "bronze")
            {
                if (BronzeGameLevels == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Bronze Game Levels are Null. Potential missing data in BronzeLevels.json file.");

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(BronzeGameLevels.Games[level - 1].words[word - 1], typeof(T));
            }
            else if (gameVersion.ToLower() == "silver")
            {

            }
        }else if (shouldReturnGamesOnly)
        {
            if (gameVersion.ToLower() == "bronze")
            {
                if (BronzeGameLevels == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Bronze Game Levels are Null. Potential missing data in BronzeLevels.json file.");

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(BronzeGameLevels.Games[level - 1], typeof(T));
            }
            else if (gameVersion.ToLower() == "silver")
            {

            }
        }
                
    }
    else throw new GameVersionOutOfRangeException();

    throw new UnreachableCodeException();
}
```

Method 1 Using Above Method

```
public string GetWord(int level, int word, string gameVersion = "bronze")
{
    var res = GetResources<Word>(level, word, gameVersion); //Error
    return res.word;
}
```

Method 2 Using the same method different type

```
public int GetTotalWordsInCurrentGame(int level, string gameVersion = "bronze")
{
    var res = GetResources<Game>(level, gameVersion: gameVersion); //Error
    return res.words.Count;
}
```

**Update**

BronzeGameLevels Declaration

```
async void LoadLevelsAsync()
{
    IJsonReader reader = DependencyService.Get<IJsonReader>();
    var bronzeLevels = await reader.ReadJsonFile("BronzeLevels.json");

    BronzeGameLevels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Level>(bronzeLevels);
}
```

Comment: How is `BronzeGameLevels` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic method `GetResources` has thet generic parameter `T` where the constraint is `T` implement `IConvertible` :

```cs
public T GetResources<T>(...) where T : IConvertible
```

To sumary, it's only possible to call this method specifying a type that implement `IConvertible`.

In you case, you call this method with the types `Game` and `Word`... that don't implement `IConvertible`, then you get this error.

The naive solution is to implement `IConvertible` in the types `Game` and `Word`, but ...

---

See this minimalist version :

```cs
public T GetResources<T>(int level, int word, bool shouldReturnGamesOnly)
{
    if (shouldReturnGamesOnly)
        return (T)BronzeGameLevels.Games[level - 1]
    else
        return (T)BronzeGameLevels.Games[level - 1].words[word - 1];
}
```

When `shouldReturnGamesOnly` is true, then the methode return a `Game`, else it return a `Word`. But it's possible to call the method with shouldReturnGamesOnly at true and expected a `Word` :

```cs
GetResources<Word>(level, word, shouldReturnGamesOnly: true); // shouldReturnGamesOnly but ask a Word ressource
```

It's just a edge case than you can ignore... but if you want improve the resilience of your code, I suggest you cut `GetResources` in two distinct methods like:

```cs
public Word GetWord(int level, int word)
{
    return BronzeGameLevels.Games[level - 1].words[word - 1];
}

public Game GetGame(int level)
{
    return BronzeGameLevels.Games[level - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've split the method into 2 methods GetWord and GetGame. Thank you for a nicely detailed explanation. Awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing what generics are meant for in C#. Your method is meant to return different types based on the value of the `shouldReturnGamesOnly` parameter.

This is not good design. Don't do this.

Instead, write two different methods, one that returns a `Game`, and one that returns a `Word`.The one that returns a `Word` can internally call the one that returns a `Game` so that you don't have duplicate code.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the answer. I didn't even know that is an actual misuse. I will make 2 functions.